# Prepared Statements - In list

Tags: c#, sql, prepared-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parameterizing a SQL IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause)

How do I translate the following query to a prepared statement (if possible..)?

```
string allemails = "aaa@aaa.aaa, bbb@bbb.bbb, ccc@ccc.ccc"; //etc...
string query = "select UNIQUE_ID users where E_MAIL in (" + allemails + ")";
//run query....
```

Can I do something like:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select UNIQUE_ID users where E_MAIL in (?)";
```

If so, what is the parameter I should add to the cmd parameters collection, and if it's varchar, how can I ask for unlimited size?

Answer (score 1):

That you are using the OdbcCommand would indicate that you are using a database other than SQL Server. SQL Server 2008 introduced [table valuded parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) which might have been a solution.

Assuming that the database that you are using does not support this feature, a split function such as the one that gjvdkamp suggested would be an option.

If your database support dynamic sql (SQL Server provides the [sp_executesql stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) for this purpose) you could also consider using that.

A final option that you might want to consider (**not very elegant**) would be to allow for a limited number of email addresses and allow each to be passed via its own parameter. You would then use them in the where clause as follows.

```
where E_MAIL in (@Address1, @Address2, @Address3)
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed reply! However, the last method is indeed not elegant since I build my allemails list dynamically...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, good one, it don;t think you can do it like that.

My take would be to rewrite the query to use a join against a set of options, and you generate that set of options from a split function.

For a split look here: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648

Then the SP would look something like this

```
Create proc GetUsersByEmail
 @EmailList varchar(8000)
as

  select unique_id
  from users u
       inner join split(@emaillist,',') e on u.e_mail = e.data
```

Actually you could also pass the sql directly without creating an SP in the DB, but I'd go for a SP.

Regards GJ

Comment: Joins cost more than a simple "in list"...

Comment: Checked that, and it's true. This approach would work but the suggested thread contains much better solutions.